# Como limpar célula do JTable ao começar a digitar?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Como posso limpar a célula no JTable ao começar a digitar em uma célula igual no excel.

Por exemplo, posiciono o cursor em uma célula e ao começar a digitar a célula entra em modo de edição, neste momento preciso de um `listener`  que ao entrar na celula o conteudo seja substitui com o que foi digitado, lembrando ao dar dois clique com o mouse o contéudo não pode limpar, apenas quando digitar algo.

Comment: Vc tentou alguma coisa? Tem algum código de base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eis a solução, não tão obvio mas que funciona.

```
public class MyJTable extends JTable {

    boolean isSelectAll = true;


    @Override
    public boolean editCellAt(int row, int column, EventObject e) {
        boolean result = super.editCellAt(row, column, e);
        selectAll(e);
        return result;
    }

    private void selectAll(EventObject e) {
        final Component editor = getEditorComponent();
        if (editor == null
                || !(editor instanceof JTextComponent)) {
            return;
        }

        if (e == null) {
            ((JTextComponent) editor).selectAll();
            return;
        }

        //  Modo de edição ao pressionar qualquer tecla
        if (e instanceof KeyEvent && isSelectAll) {
            ((JTextComponent) editor).selectAll();
            return;
        }

        //  Modo de edição ao pressionar F2
        if (e instanceof ActionEvent && isSelectAll) {
            ((JTextComponent) editor).selectAll();
            return;
        }

        //   Modo de edição ao pressionar ao dar 2 cliques com o mouse
        if (e instanceof MouseEvent && isSelectAll) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ((JTextComponent) editor).selectAll();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /*
     *  habilitar/desabilitar modo de edição para selecionar tudo ao entrar na célula
     */
    public void setSelectAllForEdit(boolean isSelectAll) {
      this.isSelectAll = isSelectAll;
    }

}
```

FONTE: https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/table-select-all-editor/